# How do I pull a single column from a c# list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, list

My code defines an LoginUser object, with a number of columns -- `LoginUserId, UserName, ActiveFlag`, etc.  I have a `List<LoginUser>` of these objects.

Right now, my code creates a `List<int>`, then iterates through the `List<LoginUser>`, inserting each `LoginUserId` into the `List<int>` in turn.

Is there a more efficient way to handle this, or some sort of built in function for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var userIds = loginUser.Select(l => l.LoginUserId);
```

Where `loginUser` is your list of LoginUser objects.

This will generate an `IQueryable<int>` which you can either enumerate as is or convert to a list (via `.ToList()`)

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ

```
List<int> userIds = (from user in userList
                select user.LoginUserId).ToList();
```